# Removing certain strings in an Access 2010 query

Tags: ms-access

I currently have an Access query that returns data in two forms

One form is 5 numbers, e.g., 12345
The other form is 2 letters, followed by 5 numbers, e.g., ab12345
This is coming in the same field, and I need to get only the numbers.  I can't strip off the first two characters, because then for the IDs that have only the numbers, I'm cutting it short.

Comment: Write a query that returns the first 2 characters in one column, call it column A, then the last 5 characters in another column, call that column B. Then filter that query by  the values in column A that are numeric.

Comment: My goal is to keep all the data, just taking two characters off when the data starts with letters. But I need all the IDs.

Comment: I gave you a solution. Just implement it.

Comment: Then I apologize, but I am failing to follow the solution you are giving.  If I have a column a that is either "12" or "ab", and I filter to only the values that are "12", don't I lose any of the IDs that still kept the two letter prefix?

Comment: You need to add the filter that will tell you if Column A is numeric or not, then you can use Column C, which would be your original ID. Actually you can probably run a simple test on the original ID to see if it's all numeric or not. That's even easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Val(string)` to strip letters after numbers.
Use `pVal(string)` to strip letters before numbers.

```
string1 =  "123456abcd1234"
val1    =  val(string1) =>    val1    =  123456

string2 =  "aqweqweasd123456abcd1234"
val2    =  pval(string2) =>   val2    =  123456
```

if in case you have "asdasd123asasd456" and you want to have 123456 as result you can modify the pval to replace all non numeric values from output

here is the pVal function. Place this in a module and use it from anywhere

```
Public Function pVal(s As String)
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        If IsNumeric(Mid(s, i, 1)) Then
            pVal = Val(Mid(s, i, Len(s)))
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a select query as source for your form like this with an expression that strips the two leading characters:

```
Select *, Mid([XX0000NumberField], 3) As NumberOnlyID
From YourTable
```

Or for mixed numbers:

```
Select *, Right([XX0000NumberField], 5) As NumberOnlyID
From YourTable
```

Comment: Except that I have some for whom that would return what I need, and others for whom it would strip off the first two numbers, leaving me with incomplete user ids.